# Show string if value is None in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

If a value is `None` I would like to show a `-` rather than rendering `None` in the table.

However I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' or '-'' from 'employee.full_name or '-''
```

I'd like to avoid doing a ton of if else statements if possible.

Here's my code:

```
  {% for employee in employees %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{employee.full_name or '-'}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.position or '-'}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.dob or '-'}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.phone or '-'}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.email or '-'}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.address or '-'}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.joined or '-'}}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

The following Python code works as expected:

```
dog = None
print(dog or '-')
```

Comment: you can use `template_tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|default_if_none`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none):

```
{% for employee in employees %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ employee.full_name|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.position|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.dob|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.phone|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.email|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.address|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.joined|default_if_none:'-' }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```